# Android encoding/decoding issues

Tags: android

Need your help again.I am getting byte[] from onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1).Now i am transferring each frame through TCP to my System and then write a JPG file with that byte[].But when i open this JPG file it says that invalid JPG file.Moreover,when i send the same byte [] from PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() method and then write a JPG file on my PC ,it works fine.

I know its a kind of encoding issue,actually byte[] which i get from onPreviewFrame is byte array of compressed image data.

I can only transfer this byte array of compressed image data through TCP from my Phone to PC.But i want to decode this data once i get this on PC.Can you guys please help me how should i proceed.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Best regards,
ZAI

Comment: Could this be related to endianness issues? I could imagine a situation where the ARM processor in the phone is big-endian and your x86 CPU is little-endian, which would mean you're putting the bytes out backward and thus not writing a proper header. Can you compare the first few bytes of your phone-generated file with an actual JPEG file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode byte[] data coming from `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1)` into JPEG format. and then send it over the network.

At receiving side you can check start and end marker of image as 0xff,0xd8 and 0xff,0xd9 respectively. You need to decode the bytes received.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the byte array that is received in the onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) is not in jpeg format. Please check your camera preview format settings and try to set jpeg as preview format (getSupportedPreviewFormats() + [setPreviewFormat(int pixel_format)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29)). However, I don't think the jpeg format is supported during camera preview mode as the compression overhead might just be too time consuming for a real-time video stream.

Jiri